# Asymmetric treatment of \mark commands on left and right pages

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I work on a dictionary like index with longtable. Using `/mark` for setting headers on facing pages in a book manually I observe a strange asymmetry, which was explained in [a blog](http://texblog.net/help/latex/markboth.html) as

> You should note that a left-hand heading is generated by the last
>   \markboth command before the end of the page, while a right-hand
>   heading is generated by the first \markboth or \markright that comes
>   on the page if there is one, otherwise by the last one before the
>   page.

I tried to see if this is indeed the source of my issue with the following MVE:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  
\usepackage{booktabs,array,microtype, longtable}
\usepackage{alltt}  % to use input with commands 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\tablefont}{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lmodern} % to avoid scalable font error
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
    some text 0  

    \markboth{firstLeft}{firstRight}  % on first page right (first seen on page)
    some text 1  

    \markboth{secondLeft}{secondRight} % no effect 

\clearpage 
some text 2 

    \markboth{thirdLeft}{thirdRight} % on second right  (first seen on page)
    % with scrbook: fourth left (last seen on page)

some text3 

\markboth{fourthLeft}{fourthRight}
some text4 

\clearpage 
    some text 5         % with header fourthRight )  -- last one seen 

\end{document}
```

The output changes when setting the document class to a book style with facing  pages: the header is not the first, but the last header marked on the page. This is incorrect for an index: the header on each page (left or right) should 
be the first entry (the first `\markboth`) value.

Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using KOMA-Script, as in your MWE, you can just use `\leftfirstmark` instead of `\leftmark` in your header:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\lehead{\leftfirstmark}

\begin{document}

some text 0

\markboth{firstLeft}{firstRight}
some text 1

\markboth{secondLeft}{secondRight}

\clearpage 
some text 2

\markboth{thirdLeft}{thirdRight}

some text 3

\markboth{fourthLeft}{fourthRight}
some text 4

\clearpage 
some text 5

\end{document}
```

---

If you are not using KOMA-Script, you can still load `scrlayer-scrpage` and use the solution above. By default, the running head is printed on the outer side of the page here, so you will have to redefine `\rehead` instead of `\lehead`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\rehead{\leftfirstmark}
```

---

If you do not want to use `scrlayer-scrpage`, you can patch `\leftmark` to use `\firstmark` instead of `\botmark`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\leftmark{\botmark}{\firstmark}{}{}
```

If `\leftmark` has not been changed by the document class or a package you loaded, this is equivalent to

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*\leftmark{\expandafter\@leftmark\firstmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother
```